Frederick the Great - Left handed Flautist
Just reading about Frederick the Great, who was supposedly a quite good flautist, but left-handed — I have a picture showing this.*
Would that have been a problem, as all the flautists I know of play right-handed?
Or is the painting plain inaccurate, opposed to Guidot's example,  which means he actually did play standard?

* I can't reproduce an image, but it's from 'Great Composers', pub. WHSmith, pg. 25. Wish I was capable, but sadly, not...
PLEASE - read my comment!

The painting guidot found shows him holding the flute normally. Please post the painting you're thinking of. Beware: make sure the original of the painting is that way, and you're not looking at a file that's been horizontally flipped. I do know of a painting that shows someone playing the flute "flipped," and a number of speculations about why; see footnote 173 on p 66 of my dissertation. I put the picture in there to make a point about the violin in the background, but have to address the flute technique.

While I'm tempted to close or downvote this question as being based on a misconception, the last sentence can be addressed. I'll write an answer eventually but the TLDR is 1) there was a standard practice in place to play right-handed; exceptions were rare, 2) practice was becoming even more standardized by Frederick's time, and the flute was evolving, and 3) he had one of the most famous people, maybe the most influential person, in the history of the instrument tutoring him personally and making him instruments. If he had needed a custom flute we'd probably know about it.

Please include an image of the painting you are referring to in your question.

I’m not sure why you think Freddy was left-handed; I can’t find anything to back this up.  In the Menzel painting he’s certainly playing right-handed.

The plot thickens!!! Having studied guidot's painting. It's exactly the opposite of the painting I have in my book! I can't explain that one, but it would lead those looking at it that Freddy was in fact playing left-handed, as the picture is a mirror image. Work that one out!!!

@Tim note that also the violinists in the photo in guidot's answer hold the instruments in a right-handed manner. It would be awkward if all musicians in the scene played in an inverted way.

@user1079505 - well spotted. Making guidot's the original. Probably why I failed the detective exam. So the question was based on false premises, and will hitherto be deleted.

@user1079505 I'm not sure whether this is what you're saying, but all the string players are holding as normal, instrument in left hand and bow in right. There is no "right-handed" manner for bowed strings; "flipped" playing is even more rare than for flute. Maybe your point is that that makes it more likely that this is the original orientation of the painting and that Tim's book has flipped the image.

@Tim The nugget that was answerable all along was "Did [or do, in modern times] flute players flip the orientation" regardless of whether Freddy did. That might actually deserve to be a separate question with the Judith Leyster painting as evidence. Also, searching this site, I find a question from someone learning Indian bansuri, and 2 minutes on Google images suggests that maybe it's played both ways.

@AndyBonner yes, exactly, my point is that the image included by guidot likely corresponds to the original.

Does the right hand have an easier job on a standard flute?  It is not obvious to me.  I don't play the flute but I play the clarinet and saxophone.  Almost all notes require the fingers of the left hand and even the thumb.  Many notes don't use any fingers of the right hand.  The right thumb supports the instrument but a flute is not very heavy.

Referring to this painting:

Frederick the Great Playing the Flute at Sanssouci — Adolph Menzel
Some issues:

On the painting he holds the flute towards the right side as normal.
Baroque traverse flutes had very few if any keys, and all the holes are on one axis, so there is much less hand-orientation built in.
One can mirror everything, but this is a drastic step. Even modern flutes seem to be built and played in mirrored format, I found a nice report here.


Many baroque winds, at least oboes, had y-shaped keys so they could be played -- in theory at least -- either way around.  But u have the feeling that flutes are not as symmetrical as they seem.

I think the proposition that it may have been common to play the baroque flute "flipped" would need a lot more support. My baroque-flute-playing faculty advisor was surprised and confused by the "flipped" flute in my question-comment. Plus, Frederick's flute probably was not symmetrical; the "Quantz flute" with its second key was made specifically for him (or at least, he was one of its first adopters).

The flute from time of Frederick the Great (the 18th century) was the baroque flute.  This instruments consists of three or four lengths of tube that connect in a straight line.  Each joint can be rotated independently so that a comfortable configuration can be achieved to suit the hands of the performer.
The baroque flute usually only had one key (D♯).  This was operated by the a little finger on the lower hand.  This key is usually designed to be vertically symmetric with respect to the body of the instruments, so playing left-handed really wouldn’t be an issue.

Image source: http://www.oldflutes.com/baroq.htm

Johann Joachim Quantz, the famous flautist, flute maker, and composer, taught Frederick flute and made instruments for him.
In 1726, Quantz invented a second key for the footjoint.  This E♭ key was for a tone hole of a slightly different size than the D♯ tone hole.  Both were necessary to play in the mean tone tuning system accurately.

Image source: soundcloud.com/elysiumensemble/quantz-flute-live]
Both keys are operated by the little finger.  To play left-handed on one of these flutes would only require that the two keys be modified, or perhaps a seperate footjoint could be constructed.
From Quantz’ On Playing the Flute (Translation by Edward R Reilly), Ch. III, §10:

If someone plays left-handed, the curved portion of the large key must be bent to the other side, and the little key also must be placed there; and they must be placed in such a way that both keys may be reached comfortably with the little finger whether they are on one side or the other. Therefore the crook of the bent key must not be too long; the bent key must be only the breadth of the little finger longer than the small key, not projecting over it, so that the little key may be depressed without touching the bent one. If you make a bent key with two crooks, like the C key  on the oboe, and place an additional little key on the other side of the flute, it can be used by anyone, whether he plays right-handed or left-handed.


Flute from the collection of Frederick the Great
SPSG Photo: Wolfgang Pfauder
Image source: https://frederick.mml.ox.ac.uk/music

The modern (Böhm system) flute, which originates in the 19th century, has a considerably different design.  For the performer, the most significant thing is probably its elaborate system of keywork required for the chromatic notes.  The keywork is made (like a glove) for the a left hand to be at the top, and a right hand to be at the bottom.
Trying to hold a modern flute left-handed just doesn’t work — you’d need an especially made left-hand model.

Your answer would have been accepted, apart from the fact that, as noted in my comment, the picture in my book was in fact, the wrong way round. I cannot delete my question, wish I could. Now to get the egg off my face...

@Tim Why can't you delete your question? As the author this is usually trivial. (Also, just remember that accepting an answer just means it was helpful, not that it was necessarily correct. You could also answer your own question and accept that answer, so at least it's clear the issue has been resolved to your satisfaction.)

@Aaron - I did try yesterday, and a flag came up, to the effect that folk had tried hard to answer, so was not allowed. Now I try, but there's no available sensible reason shown. Will try again, though.

@Tim I've seen that same message, but the one I've seen just asks if you're sure; it doesn't prevent deletion.
